# Javascript - Why won't my incorrect answer counter increment like my correct answer counter does?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, increment

I'm trying to increment an incorrect answer counter, for some reason this isn't working. The correct answer counter is working fine so I've tried a similar process in making it a function but no luck. I've tried adding it as separate if statement and also inside the `if (selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer)` statement.

You can ignore the qualifying points because that is part of another counter, I just also want a counter that increments correct and incorrect answers. The `correctScore ()` function works fine, so why doesn't the incorrect one when I place it after `correctScore ();`?
Hope that makes sense.

```js
let classToApply = 'incorrect-answer';
if (selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer) {
  qualifyingPointsScore();
  correctScore();
  classToApply = 'correct-answer';

  /*selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);*/
}

function correctScore() {
  correctAnswers += 1;
  document.getElementById("correct-score").innerText = correctAnswers;
}

function incorrectScore() {
  incorrectAnswers += 1;
  document.getElementById("incorrect-score").innerText = incorrectAnswers;
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="scores-container">
  <div class="scores-area">
    <p class="scores">Correct Answers: <span id="correct-score">0</span></p>
    <p class="scores">Incorrect Answers: <span id="incorrect-score">0</span></p>
    <p class="scores">Total Questions <span id="question-counter">0</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Your provided code snippet has some obvious errors in it

Comment: you aren't calling the `incorrectScore()` function anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an else part to the if-statement

```
...

if (selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer) {
  qualifyingPointsScore();
  correctScore();
  classToApply = 'correct-answer';
 } else {
  incorrectScore();
 }
 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much - Seems so silly now... I swear I tried calling that function over and over in an else statement, not sure what I was doing wrong... probably did it with another 'if' statement or something silly. I'm a beginner so thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer) {
  qualifyingPointsScore();
  correctScore();
  classToApply = 'correct-answer';

  /*selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);*/
}
else{
incorrectScore();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - Seems so silly now... I swear I tried calling that function over and over in an else statement, not sure what I was doing wrong... probably did it with another 'if' statement or something silly. I'm a beginner so thanks for this.